# Homeomorphic metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I want to examine if $(0,1] $ and $\mathbb R $ are homeomorphic. We work on metric space $(\mathbb R, e)$, where $e$ stands for the euclidean metric.

My answer:

Let's assume there is a homeomorphism $f: \mathbb R \to (0,1]$.

Let's consider $A= \mathbb R- f^{-1} (1)$, which is disconnected.

Then, $f_A: A \to (0,1) $ and $(0,1)$ is connected. Thus, $f$ cannot be homeomorphism, due to   an homeomorpism preserves connectedness.

I guess that's the actual implication of orangeskid's answer.

**Edited**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HINT: Removing any point from $\mathbb{R}$ produces a subspace that is not connected, while removing $1$ from $(0,1]$ leaves a connected subspace.

Comment: Now, I see! And you take advantage of the fact that connectedness is a a topological property!

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is probably the one given by orangeskid. Another possibility is to notice that $\mathbb{R}$ has two [ends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_(topology)) whereas $(0,1]$ has only one end.

In the same way, the one-point compactifications of $\mathbb{R}$ and $(0,1]$ are respectively the circle $\mathbb{S}^1$ and $[0,1]$: they are not homeomorphic so the spaces $\mathbb{R}$ and $(0,1]$ themself are not homeomorphic.